# Error: Returned error: invalid opcode: SHR

Tags: go-ethereum

[image]

I am getting this error while migrating

```
Contract:
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;
contract Hello {
   string message;

   constructor() public {

   message = "Hello, World";

   }
   function getGreetings() public view returns (string memory)
   {
     return message;
   }
   function setGreetings(string memory _message) public{
     message = _message;
   }

}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var Hello = artifacts.require("./Hello.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Hello);
};
```

Comment: And Yes I am Deploying it on local ethereum. not in ganache-cli

Comment: What is your genesis file? It should be missing the fork that enabled SHR opcode.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed adding

```
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"constantinopleBlock": 0
```

to genesis.json fixed the problem for me, as the SHR opcode is a recent addition to geth in the Constantinople release (and byzantiumBlock must be added in order to add constantinopleBlock).

Answer (score 2):

SO the Problem was in my genesis block, I wrote genesis.json myself so some parameters were missing. then I used *puppeth* to create new genesis block and that how i solve.

Answer (score 2):

Adding "byzantiumBlock": 0, and "constantinopleBlock": 0, to my genesis fixed the issued. My full genesis looks like:

```
 {
  "config": {  
    "chainId": XXX, 
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "eip145Block": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "difficulty": "0x400",
  "gasLimit": "0x8000000", 
  "alloc": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you successfully migrated before..

Delete all files in --> truffle/build/contracts

Answer (score -1):

Following up with @tqd's answer, please put it in the "config" block of the genesis.json, not in the root. Wasted so much of my time.

Comment: Please, next time specify it as a comment on the answer of a user rather than in a separate answer.