# Invalid Opcode Error SHR

Tags: evm, error, cpp-ethereum, opcode

```
call to UniswapV2Factory.INIT_CODE_HASH
call to UniswapV2Factory.INIT_CODE_HASH errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.

  "code": -32000,
  "message": "invalid opcode: SHR"
```

I'm trying to fork Uniswap to another EVM blockchain and I'm getting this error when trying to call some functions.

---

```
    {
  "config": {    
    "chainId": 660868,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
```

Here genesis file

Comment: I guess your other blockchain has a different version of EVM where some opcodes don't exist

Comment: Do you have the EVM genesis file? It seems they haven't enabled the hardfork that introduced those opcodes, Constantinople.

Comment: The genesis file is missing the Constantinople fork. Here is similar question with the changes needed to the genesis file https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87245/error-returned-error-invalid-opcode-shr.